# Grammatical case vs semantic case

Tags: terminology, morphology, grammar, cases, morphological-typology

I'm not sure what these terms mean. In my lecture notes I wrote that grammatical case is used to show the syntactic functions of a nominal syntagm, depending on its relation to the verb. Semantic case, on the other hand, doesn't show the syntactic function but rather the semantic one.

As I don't have any examples for this, I find it hard to understand. Could this for example mean that even though a certain nominal syntagm is grammaticaly in accusative (so there are affixes for accusative) it actually has attributive meaning (so semantically it's genitive)?

Comment: Would that mean that some languages actually *have* semantic cases instead of grammatical ones, or is it just a different way of analyzing the grammar of sentences in languages with cases?

Comment: @LjL As I understand it no, languages don't "have" semantic cases, it's just that grammatical cases in languages can express different semantic meanings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty much it. Languages do some idiosyncratic stuff with their grammatical cases:

> I remember you *(obj)*. (English)
>   Meminī tuī *(gen)*. (Latin)
>   Ich errinere an dich *(acc)*. (Northern German)

Sometimes, sentences with the same semantic meaning even use different grammatical cases, like in Ancient Greek (transliterated):

> *Mnēmoneúō sé* (with accusative)
>   *Mémnēmai soû* (with genitive)

Yet in all of these examples, the last word is, semantically, the thing being remembered (the "theme"). The syntax doesn't change that.

Comment: Isn't it "sich erinnern", reflexive?

Comment: @Wilson To my understanding _errinern an_ is a Northern dialectal form that demonstrates my point better; however I'm not a native speaker